# Facebook Like Button not showing in webkit

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm attempting to add a Facebook Like button to my website. I have the code in place and it's working on FireFox, but on Chrome it's not showing up.

For some reason when I'm working with the official Facebook like button 'creator' in Chrome, the like button will not show up when I change the URL from the default. It does however work in chrome.

I'm not sure what the problem could be, and it might be my code, so I'll add it below:

**New HTML tag**

```html
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

**Code for initializing the button (Copy pasted directly from Facebook**

```html
<!-- Facebook -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&status=0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**Code for the button (Also copy pasted directly from Facebook)**

```html
<fb:like href="https://www.facebook.com/wildblueberries" width="87" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" send="false"></fb:like>
```

Oh and if you would like to test out the problem this is the page on facebook that I'm trying to use to create the button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ Try to change the "URL to Like" in Chrome. And the whole like button preview will vanish.

**Update:** Here is the link to the Facebook like button (It's created by their iFrame) This works in Firefox, but not Chrome/Safari: https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&channel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fstatic.ak.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter.php%3Fversion%3D26%23cb%3Df1732ea1fbdacbc%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwildblueberries.com%252Fffb6e0ef554b96%26domain%3Dwildblueberries.com%26relation%3Dparent.parent&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fwildblueberries&node_type=link&width=90&layout=button_count&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&send=false&extended_social_context=false

**Update 2** This problem only occurs if you're not logged into Facebook through your browser. Once I logged in the problem was fixed. Only problem is that not everyone in the world is logged into Facebook. So I'm still stuck with a broken Facebook like button. Any suggestions? - Thanks!

**Update 3** After figuring out that only logged in users could see the like button, I searched Google and the fan page I'm linking to probably has demographic filters.

**Update 4: After removing demographic filters from the fan page, the problem was fixed.**